# Maximum reasonable size for stemCompletion in tm?

Tags: r, tm

I have a corpus of 26 plain text files, each between 12 - 148kb, total of 1.2Mb. I'm using R on a Windows 7 laptop.

I did all the normal cleanup stuff (stopwords, custom stopwords, lower case, numbers) and want to do stem completion. I am using the original corpus as a dictionary as shown in the examples. I tried a couple of simple vectors to make sure it would work at all (with about 5 terms) and it did and very quickly.

```
exchanger <- function(x) stemCompletion(x, budget.orig)
budget <- tm_map(budget, exchanger)
```

It's been working since yesterday at 4pm!  In R Studio under diagnostics, the request log shows new requests with different request numbers. Task manager shows it using some memory, but not a crazy amount. I don't want to stop it because what if it's almost there?  Any other ideas of how to check progress - it's a volatile corpus, unfortunately?  Ideas on how long it should take? I thought about using the dtm names vector as a dictionary, cut off at the most frequent (or high tf-idf), but I'm reluctant to kill this process.

This is a regular windows 7 laptop with lots of other things running.

Is this corpus too big for stemCompletion? Short of moving to Python, is there a better way to do stemCompletion or lemmatize vice stem - my web searching has not yielded any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a definite answer without data that reproduces your problem, but I would guess the bottleneck comes from the folllowing line from the `stemCompletion` source code:

```
possibleCompletions <- lapply(x, function(w) grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE))
```

After which, given you've kept the completion heuristic on the default of "prevalent", this happens:

```
possibleCompletions <- lapply(possibleCompletions, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))
structure(names(sapply(possibleCompletions, "[", 1)), names = x)
```

That first line loops through each word in your corpus and checks it against your dictionary for possible completions. I'm guessing you have many words that appear many times in your corpus. That means the function is being called many times only to give the same response. A possibly faster version (depending on how many words were repeats and how often they were repeated) would look something like this:

```
y <- unique(x)

possibleCompletions <- lapply(y, function(w) grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE))

possibleCompletions <- lapply(possibleCompletions, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))

z <- structure(names(sapply(possibleCompletions, "[", 1)), names = y)

z[match(x, names(z))]
```

So it only loops through the unique values of `x` rather than every value of `x`. To create this revised version of the code, you would need to download the source from CRAN and modify the function (I found it in the completion.R in the R folder).

Or you may just want to use Python for this one.

Comment: thanks for this reply - not comfortable with messing with the source... but could I put these commands in a script in the script window of RStudio? I guess only if I put the full source in, which is essentially like editing the source and saving?

Comment: You're exactly right. Copy the full function out of the source into a separate script and then make your edits. Each time you need to use it, load the package, then load your custom function to replace what was loaded from the package.

Answer (score 0):

Cristina, following Schaun I recomend you use just unique word for apply stemcompletion. I mean, it is easy for your PC do completion in your unique words them do the completition in all your corpus (with all repetitions).

1. First of all, take the unique words from your corpus. For exemplo:

   unique$text   <- unique(budget)
2. Them, you can get the unique words from your original text

   unique_budget.orig <- unique(budget.orig)
3. Now, you can apply the stemcomplection for your unieque words

   unique$completition <- budget %>% stemCompletion (dictionary= unique_budget.orig)
4. Now you have an object with all words from your corpus and their completion. you just  have to apply a join between your corpus and the object unique. Be sure both objects have the same variable name for words without the completition: this gonne be the key.

This gonna reduce the number of operation your PC have to do.